# How to add multiply dns zone files via dnscmd

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dns-hosting, dns-zone, windows-dns

I have current Windows DNS server which is hosting something around 500 standard (non-AD) zones. I need transfer all of them to the new server. I copied .dns files from C:\Windows\System32\DNS from current to new server. However, they didn't appear. I googled and found that I need to use dnscmd command to add zones from files. Syntax for one zone is very clear for me, it should be

```
dnscmd nsserver /zoneadd domain.com /primary /file C:\Windows\System32\DNS\domain.com.dns
```

However, what should I do to add 500 files? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have the command you want to execute for your 500 files figured out, you can do this by just applying basic automation (no Windows DNS specifics required).

A simple `FOR` loop in `CMD` seems like the obvious approach for the [`DNSCMD /zoneadd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_22) command you provided, eg something like:

```
FOR %f IN (C:\Windows\System32\DNS\*.dns) DO dnscmd nsserver /zoneadd %~nf /primary /file %f
```

(provided you simply want to do this for all the matching files in that directory)

Alternatively you could take a more modern approach using Powershell instead. The [`Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649876.aspx) cmdlet appears to provide the equivalent functionality of your `DNSCMD` command.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply. I'm trying to run your command but have this:
C:\Windows\system32>dnscmd localhost /zoneadd domain
.com /primary /file C:\Windows\System32\DNS\domain.c
om.dns

Command failed:  DNS_ERROR_FILE_WRITEBACK_FAILED     9654    0x25B6